# miscdevice node permission needs to be generic

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I want to be able to give access to all users to my driver. I want to be able to give a 660 device node permission to my driver node. The driver node is created as apart of the miscdevice registration through the framework. But I always get the /dev/mydev with 600 permissions with users/group as root. How do I change the permission to get 660 i.e crwrw--

Comment: why `chgrp` `chown` does not help changing permissions of `/dev/mydev`?

Comment: No manual interaction. I do not wish tio write scripts that manually change that. In addition the device permission can only be changed by sudo. So better u-dev or driver than a shell sript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't change permissions for your device file in `/dev` just by modifying your driver code. It's because files in `/dev` are not created by kernel. They are created by [udev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Udev) (on PC Linux) or some other device manager. So you need to deal with `udev` to do so. More specifically, you need to create so called **udev rule**.

Also, if you want to give read/write access to your device for **all users**, you need to setup **666** permission mode, not **660** as you mentioned. It's because your device file has `root:root` as user/group, and first two digits in permission mode are for user/group. Third digit is for **others**, which you actually want to change.

Given all mentioned information into account, you can do next. Create your udev rules file (e.g. `99-my-misc-dev.rules`):

```
$ sudo vim /etc/udev/rules.d/99-my-misc-dev.rules
```

And paste next line to this file:

```
KERNEL=="mymiscdevice", MODE="0666"
```

Of course you should change `mymiscdevice` to your device's file name (as it displayed in `/dev`).

Tell `udev` to reload all rules:

```
$ sudo udevadm trigger
```

Now you should see `666` permissions for your device file.

Note that on embedded devices you usually don't have `udev`, but files in `/dev` are still created by some device manager or script. For example, if you use BusyBox rootfs, there is device manager there called `mdev`. You also can create rules for `mdev`, in `/etc/mdev.conf`. Once rule created, you should run `mdev -s` command. See [this](http://quirk.ch/2010/01/how-to-set-up-mdev-rules-for-busybox) for details.

On Android this stuff is usually done in `/init.rc` file (in Android ramdisk).